# Multiple inner joins on results

Tags: mysql, sum, inner-join

I have 4 tables:
-system_users
-quotes
-quote_items
-new_products

where

```
system_users.id = quotes.created_by
quotes.id = quote_items.quote_id
new_products.id = quote_items.new_product_id
```

I'm trying to find the total quoted value (price) for a specific store (system_users.store_id)
I have this so far which is not working:

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM( s.price),2)
    FROM quotes
    INNER JOIN system_users
    ON quotes.created_by = system_users.id
    INNER JOIN quote_items p 
    ON p.id = quote_id  Where system_users.store_id = 14
    INNER JOIN new_products s 
    ON s.id = new_product_id
    Where system_users.store_id = 1
```

The query is definately failing at the second INNER JOIN which I don't understand why.
The first join should get all the quotes by all the users at a specific store.
The second join should get all the quote_items with the quote_ids from the results above.
The third join should get the products from the new results and sum the prices.

Comment: When you say "failing", it would be helpful if you could be explicit how you've determined it is failing.  Is the value returned incorrect for an example?  If so, can you provide a minimal example of the contents of the tables for that query and the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the `WHERE` clause twice in the query

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM( s.price),2)
    FROM quotes
    INNER JOIN system_users
    ON quotes.created_by = system_users.id
    INNER JOIN quote_items p 
    ON p.id = quote_id  AND system_users.store_id = 14
    INNER JOIN new_products s 
    ON s.id = new_product_id
    Where system_users.store_id = 1
```

You can use `AND` in the `ON` clause for joining with multiple conditions

Comment: apologies, that should not be there. thanks

Comment: @mrcurious So, why's it still there !?!?